# IsNullOrEmpty(string) and List.Count > 0 in mustache-sharp

Tags: c#, template-engine, mustache

I use [mustache-sharp](https://github.com/jehugaleahsa/mustache-sharp) as template engine

I want to know Is there anyway by using this template engine and have two conditions for checking

```
1) IsNullOrEmpty(string)  => e.g. {{#IsNullOrEmpty MyName}}} {{/IsNullOrEmpty}}
2) List.Count > 0         => e.g. {{#Any Persons}} {{/Any}}
```

Can anyone guide me How can I create tags like above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to create a custom **ContentTagDefinition** and register it in **HtmlFormatCompiler**.

For example:

1. **IsNullOrEmpty**

   ```
   public class IsNullOrEmptyTagDefinition : ContentTagDefinition
   {
       private const string conditionParameter = "condition";

       public IsNullOrEmptyTagDefinition()
           : base("IsNullOrEmpty")
       {}

       public override IEnumerable<TagParameter> GetChildContextParameters()
       {
           return new TagParameter[0];
       }

       public override bool ShouldGeneratePrimaryGroup(Dictionary<string, object> arguments)
       {
           object condition = arguments[conditionParameter];
           return isConditionSatisfied(condition);
       }

       protected override IEnumerable<TagParameter> GetParameters()
       {
           return new TagParameter[] { new TagParameter(conditionParameter) { IsRequired = true } };
       }

       protected override bool GetIsContextSensitive()
       {
           return false;
       }

       private bool isConditionSatisfied(object condition)
       {
           if (condition == null)
           {
               return true;
           }

           return condition is string ? string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition as string) : false;
       }

   }
   ```
2. **Any**

   ```
   public class AnyTagDefinition : ContentTagDefinition
   {
       private const string conditionParameter = "condition";

       public AnyTagDefinition()
           : base("Any")
       {}

       public override IEnumerable<TagParameter> GetChildContextParameters()
       {
           return new TagParameter[0];
       }

       public override bool ShouldGeneratePrimaryGroup(Dictionary<string, object> arguments)
       {
           object condition = arguments[conditionParameter];
           return isConditionSatisfied(condition);
       }

       protected override IEnumerable<TagParameter> GetParameters()
       {
           return new TagParameter[] { new TagParameter(conditionParameter) { IsRequired = true } };
       }

       protected override bool GetIsContextSensitive()
       {
           return false;
       }

       private bool isConditionSatisfied(object condition)
       {
           if (condition is IEnumerable)
           {
               return (condition as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().Any();
           }

           return false;
       }

   }
   ```
3. Register both tags

   ```
   HtmlFormatCompiler compiler = new HtmlFormatCompiler();
   compiler.RegisterTag(new IsNullOrEmptyTagDefinition(), true);
   compiler.RegisterTag(new AnyTagDefinition(), true);
   ```